# Object #<Object> has no method '_renderItemData'

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement an advanced example of jquery.ui.autocomplete widget with categories (  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories ). My code basically looks just like in this example's source code but for some reason, when i'll type something in input field, autosuggest don't work and i'm getting this error in object inspector javascript console:

```
Object #<Object> has no method '_renderItemData'
```

Have you any idea what am i possibily doing wrong? The basic example works fine on my website. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you double check the url of the script?  does the example work on the same page or a different page?  If your jQuery wrapped in the document ready function?  Can you post your code?

Comment: data array declaration and binding autosuggest to input field is in ready function, the `catcomplete()` declaration is outside the ready function. example works on the same page. It's hard to post my code cause it's used in rails app but i'll try to clear it a bit: https://gist.github.com/4154343

Comment: What version of jQueryUI are you using? `_renderItemData` is new for 1.9.

Comment: yes that was it, i was using 1.8.x, thank you :) Please post your comment as a question to make me able to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 9):

Use  method `_renderItem` instead of `_renderItemData`. The example is wrong.